# Как сделать swiper, во всю ширину?

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery, swiper

Всем привет! Столкнулся с проблемой что не все слайды показываются во всю ширину. Вот что мне надо сделать по макету -
[image: Что нужно сделать]
А вот что получается у меня ( добавил серый бг что бы видно было )
[image: Что у меня]

Не знаю как поправить
Вот код
html:

```
        <div class="swiper">
        <div class="swiper-wrapper">
        <div class="swiper-slide" >
            <div class="card">
                <div class="feedback__info">
                    <div class="feedback__flex">
                        <img src="img/png/feedback_photo.png" alt="image">
                    <div class="feedback__name">
                        <p class="feedback__name--text">Алексей Гончаров</p>
                        <p class="feedback__company--text">CEO of Products</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                    <p class="feedback__descr--text">
                        В действительности, это правда лучшие серверва, которые были в моём использованные за все года. Отныне,<br> Onyx завоевали моё сердце.
                    </p>
                </div>
        </div>
(swiper-slide - повторяется ещё 7 раз)
```

css:

```
.swiper {
    width: 100%;
    height: 20.6rem;
```

}

js:

```
 const swiper = new Swiper('.swiper', {
    spaceBetween: 30,
    loop: true,
    slidesPerView: 5.5,
    centeredSlides: true,
    initialSlide: 6,
    freemode: true,
    parralax:true,
    speed:2000,
    keyboard: true,
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Вы не к тому элементу подключаете плагин. Судя по тому, что вы тут пытались показать... надо вызывать на элементе `swiper-slide`

Comment: Если я подключу, вот так. То свайпер вообще перестает работать((
const swiper = new Swiper('.swiper-slide', {
    spaceBetween: 50,
    loop: true,
    slidesPerView: 5.5,
    centeredSlides: true,
});

Comment: Возможно вы где-то тег не закрыли. Есть рабочий пример https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/d5128j?file=%2Findex.html Замените на свои карточки.

Comment: Похоже я где то и в правду забыл закрыть скобку. Починил, теперь всё работает. Спасибо большое!